# Display AJAX JSON result via JQUERY - separate fields?

Tags: jquery, mysql, json

Im pulling a JSON result from MYSQL using JQUERY.
Im then displaying the result in a loop in order to fill a UL list.

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
url='<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/chat/comments/';

$.getJSON(url , function(data) {
var tbl_body = "";
$.each(data, function() {
    var tbl_row = "";
    $.each(this, function(k , v) {
        tbl_row += ""+v+"";
    })
    tbl_body += "<li>"+tbl_row+"</li>";                 
})
$("#table1").html(tbl_body);
});

}, 1000);
```

This displays the results as

```
CommentName
```

I want to have the Name in italics and the comment in plain text like

Comment - *Name*

How would i go about seperating the name from the comment so i can make it italic?

Cheers

Comment: What's exactly in the JSON response ?

Comment: Doesnt matter i was being silly...

fixed it with this

    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function ()
    {
    url='<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/chat/comments/';

    $.getJSON(url , function(data) {
    var tbl_body = "";
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        var comment = data[i].comment;
        var name = data[i].name;
        tbl_body += "<li>"+comment+"- <i>"+name+"</i></li>";                 
    })
    $("#table1").html(tbl_body);
    });

    }, 1000);

Thanks anyway!

Comment: Adam, make an answer from your comment (if that works) and accept it. This will be cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably do this :

```
$.each(data, function() {
    tbl_body += data[0] + ' <i>' + data[1] + '</i>';                 
})
```

or

```
$.each(data, function() {
    tbl_body += data.comment + ' <i>' + data.name + '</i>';                 
})
```

But it's hard to guess without the JSON structure (probably an array and not an object because with a plain object there would be risks about the iteration order).

Comment: Note that in HTML5 the meaning of the <i> tag can be slightly different. It might be a better idea to put the text in a span and style it with css. Something like '<span class="italic">'+data[1]+'</span>' and a css rule that says span.italic { font-style: italic }